# How do I multiply data in mySQL database to simulate scale?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, scalability

Input:

A database consisting of

- static tables that do not scale with number of users or time
- dynamic tables that grow when users interact with the application (so scale with number of users and time)
- a database with real life data for x users

Task:

- scale the database to simulate larger number of users

Example:

```
Tables: 

t_user (scale target)
UserId , Name
1 , John
2, Terry

t_post (dynamic)
AuthorId, PostId, TagId
1, 1 , 1
1, 2 , 2
1, 3 , 2
2, 4 , 1

t_tag (static)
TagId, Name
1, C#
2, Java
```

Desired output with scale factor = 2

```
t_user
UserId , Name
1 , John
2, Terry
3 , John
4, Terry

t_post (dynamic)
AuthorId, PostId, TagId
1, 1 , 1
1, 2 , 2
1, 3 , 2
2, 4 , 1
1, 5 , 1
1, 6 , 2
1, 7 , 2
2, 8 , 1

t_tag (static)
TagId, Name
1, C#
2, Java
```

Ofcourse for such a small database this can be done in MySQL but I need a solution that will work for a database with 150+ tables (writing a scaling routine for each is not a solution) and scale factors that will bring a database form 100 to up to 10 000 users.

Does anyone know a dedicated tool or hack that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with writing my own script. Below you will find a simplified version (many columns in tables are ommited for clarity). This worked very well. I was able to scale the DB by a factor of 100 quite efficiently. Hope this helps

```
SET autocommit = 0;

START TRANSACTION;

SET @UMAX = (SELECT MAX(UserID) AS MX FROM t_user);
SET @QSMAX = (SELECT MAX(QuestionSetID) AS MX FROM t_question_set);
SET @QGMAX = (SELECT MAX(QuestionGroupID) AS MX FROM t_question_group);
SET @QMAX = (SELECT MAX(QuestionID) AS MX FROM t_question);
SET @TMAX = (SELECT MAX(TestID) AS MX FROM t_test);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t_seq;
CREATE table t_seq AS
    (
    SELECT
        1 S
    );
INSERT INTO t_seq (S) VALUES (2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);    


INSERT INTO `t_user`
    (
        `UserID`,
        `Login`,
        `Password`,
    )
SELECT
    `UserID` + 1000000 + @UMAX * t_seq.S,
    concat(if(Login is null, '', Login), `UserID` + 1000000 + @UMAX * t_seq.S),
    `Password`,
FROM t_user,
    t_seq;

INSERT INTO `t_question_set`(`QuestionSetID`) 
SELECT `QuestionSetID` + 1000000 + @QSMAX * t_seq.S 
FROM t_question_set,t_seq;   

INSERT INTO `t_question_group`(
    `QuestionGroupID`, 
    `QuestionSetID`
    )
SELECT 
  `QuestionGroupID` + 1000000 + @QGMAX * t_seq.S,  
  `QuestionSetID` + 1000000 + @QSMAX * t_seq.S, 
FROM t_question_group,t_seq;

INSERT INTO `t_question`(`QuestionID`, `QuestionGroupID`)
SELECT
  `QuestionID` + 1000000 + @QMAX * t_seq.S, 
  `QuestionGroupID` + 1000000 + @QGMAX * t_seq.S, 
FROM t_question, t_seq;

INSERT INTO `t_test`
    (
        `TestID`,
        `QuestionSetID`,
        `UserID`,
            )
SELECT
    `TestID` + 1000000 + @TMAX * t_seq.S,
    `QuestionSetID` + 1000000 + @QSMAX * t_seq.S,
    `UserID` + 1000000 + @UMAX * t_seq.S,
FROM t_test,t_seq;

INSERT INTO `t_question_answer`(
    `QuestionID`, 
    `TestID`
    )
SELECT 
  `QuestionID` + 1000000 + @QMAX * t_seq.S,
  `TestID` + 1000000 + @TMAX * t_seq.S,
FROM t_question_answer,t_seq;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Benchmark Factory for Databases](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/Benchmark-Factory-for-Databases-Freeware.shtml) looks like it might do what you need it to, or you could give the [MySQL Benchmark Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/benchmarks.html) a try.

Comment: Here's the [User Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fus-downloads.quest.com%2FRepository%2Fsupport.quest.com%2FBenchmark%2520Factory%2520for%2520Database%2F6.5%2FDocumentation%2FBenchmark%2520Factory%2520for%2520Databases%2520User%2520Guide.pdf&ei=qLwNUeeGLpDbigKD9YDYBg&usg=AFQjCNFD35q8fA6-0KHvZTkCI80P_WciBQ&sig2=4ePcuURwaqGjtDY3SAn1Uw&bvm=bv.41867550,d.cGE)

Comment: not very helpful. I was looking for an actual solution to this specific problem, not a link to a user guide. But thanks for trying. I ended up with writing my own script.